# Rails comparing zipcode based on user input against db and then mailing to employee

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a Customer form that is not storing data but has a form that is then pushing the data to a contact. What I'd like to do is when the customer enters in their data is to take the zipcode from the form, compare it against all zipcodes and if it matches, send their contact information to the manager in their region.

In a nutshell Bill enters in 10001 and that matches the Zipcodes db which has a Region ID of 3. So the manager of Region 3 gets the email.

For the models I have:

```
Zipcode
belongs_to :region

Region
has_many :zipcodes, dependent: :destroy

Contact
include ActiveModel::Model
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :company, :region, :email, :message_for_mailer, :inquiry, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode
```

In my ContactsController I have the following for the create:

```
 def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  @contact.valid?
  if captcha?
   ContactMailer.contact_request(@contact).deliver if @contact.valid?
  else
   @contact.errors.add(:base, 'Please verify you are human')
  end
  respond_with @contact
 end
```

My thought was the following:

```
def create
 @zipcode = Zipcode.all
 @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
 @contact.valid?
 if captcha?
   if @contact.zipcode == @zipcode.zipcode
     ContactMailer.custom_request(@contact).deliver if @contact.valid?
   else
     ContactMailer.basic_request(@contact).deliver if @contact.valid?
   end
 else
   @contact.errors.add(:base, 'Please verify you are human')
 end
 respond_with @contact
end
```

But I'm pretty sure this won't work as I'm not actually comparing against the db. So how do I iterate over the Zipcode table with the results of the data that's being created?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) to create a job that can be performed after the response is sent. This makes the application more snappy as the user does not have wait for the email to be sent and frees up your web threads.

```
class ContactNotifierJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default 
  def perform(contact)
    @zipcode = ZipCode.find_by(zipcode: contact.zipcode)
    @manager = @zipcode.try(:region).try(:manager)
    if @manager
      ContactMailer.notify_manager(@contact, @manager).deliver
    else
      ContactMailer.do_something_else(@contact).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

You can then simply spool up the job from your controller:

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  @contact.errors.add(:base, 'Please verify you are human') unless captcha? 
  if @contact.save
    ContactNotifierJob.perform_later(@contact)
  end
  respond_with @contact
end
```

It will be performed as soon as the queuing system is free.

Comment: This is interesting...I mean it fails with uninitialized constant ContactsController::ContactNotifierJob but it's an interesting approach

Comment: Did you actually place the job class in the correct file? That error is more indicative of a botched implementation and not the code in this answer.

Comment: Yeah...that moment when you realize contact_notification_job is not the same as contact_notifier_job.

Comment: I did have to make a change in the controller to: ContactNotifierJob.perform_later(@contact) if @contact.valid? since I'm not actually saving the data but checking validity. But then it's failing ActiveJob::SerializationError:
       Unsupported argument type: Contact. So I tried switching passing @contact to contact_params. Getting an issue on uninitialized constant ContactNotifierJob::ZipCode

Comment: `ContactNotifierJob.perform_later(@contact) if @contact.valid?`  - Nope. Save the record and check the return value. If its truthy the record is valid. Besides you can't/should not send a notification if the record was not persisted anyways.

Comment: And you can only pass a model instance to ActiveJob if it has been saved. If you don't want to save the record for whatever reason you need to convert it to a hash and pass that to the Job.
 https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for #<Contact:0x00007fac35f45400>

Comment: Well the problem is that your model does not inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` - if you want to persist it to the db you need to create a table and setup the class to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` (or ApplicationModel which is a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base). If you are not going to persist the data use `ContactNotifierJob.perform_later(@contact.to_h)`. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#supported-types-for-arguments

Comment: IMHO I would save the data to a DB as well as just sending an email. Email is finicky and you don't want to lose data / potential leads.